# In AWS Resolver Mapping Template, is there any method for removing a field from an object?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-appsync, vtl

I'm writing code for my `GraphQL` resolvers in AWS `AppSync` with resolver mapping template.

I know that there is a `put` mehtod that I can use for add a field to input object or any other object. Like this (for example):

```
$util.qr($name.put("firstName", "$ctx.args.input.firstName"))
```

But now I want to remove a field from an object, for example, the input object.
Is there any mehtod similar to the `put` method but for removing a field. something like:

```
$util.qr($ctx.args.input.remove("firstName"))
```

I am new to AWS and `DynamoDB` and `AppSync`.( you can consider me as an absolute beginner. )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `foreach` and make a new array.

```
#set($newInput={})

#foreach ($key in $ctx.args.input.keySet())
  #if($key!="firstName")
     $util.qr($newInput.put($key, $ctx.args.input.get($key)))
  #end
#end
```

Comment: So actually you didn't remove it. you move other fields to a new one. like examples I saw... could be good. so isn't a way to really remove that field from the `input` itself?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, generally you can use `$myObject.remove("myKey")` on objects that you create in a mapping template, however, I will add the disclaimer that this will not always work on objects in the $ctx as some parts are immutable. AppSync bundles [utility methods](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/resolver-util-reference.html) that make dealing with objects in mapping templates easier (e.g. making copies of objects). This functionality is actually tied to that of [Apache Velocity](https://velocity.apache.org/) so you can read more about how it works in those docs.

Comment: Utility methods are convenient but VTL functionality is restricted because macros are blocked. That might change though (please please please...!): https://github.com/aws/aws-appsync-community/issues/90

Answer (score 1):

In AppSync, the arguments in a query or mutation are exposed in the request mapping template as `$context.args`. If you have passed in an argument named `input` you can remove it as follows:

`$util.quiet($context.args.remove("input"))`

or its using the alias for quiet (identical to the above):

`$util.qr($context.args.remove("input"))`

This can be used in both the request and response mapping template. It can also be used to remove nested properties:

`$util.qr($context.args.input.remove("nestedProp"))`